# How to delete everything on an iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

I would like to give my iPod touch as a gift to someone I know, but I want to be sure that there is nothing left on it to avoid giving data with it...

How do I clean the iPod ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Fully charge the iPod Touch
2. Go to the Settings menu. Scroll down until you see the "General" settings, and hit that, then scan to the very bottom, where you'll see a mini-menu titled "Reset." Press this. This will bring up a few different options, but the one you want is "Erase All Content and Settings." (`Settings / General / Reset / Erase all` )

you can see full detailed [here](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/1927444/how_to_securely_erase_an_ipod_touch.html).

Also you can use itunes, and go to the [restore feature](http://www.apple.com/support/ipodtouch/assistant/ipodtouch/index.html#section_4). This will take your ipod back to factory default.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest [renaming the iPod](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1789), which you can do by clicking the name in iTunes after you selected it. Then just type the new name. If I recall correctly resetting it does not remove the name.

[image: Selecting the iPod in iTunes]

Answer (score 0):

1, erase all the data from your iPod touch by goning to: Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.

2, restore your iPod touch using iTunes. Refer to the following picture.

[image: restore iPad from iTunes]

3, use data eraser.